# Increase the Duration of a Toast

Tags: android, android-toast

Currently there only exist two duration for a Toast: `Toast.LENGTH_SHORT` and `Toast.LENGTH_LONG`...

But what if you want to increase the duration of a Toast in Android?

Here is a hack I came up with and wanted to share:

```
public void createToast(Context context, String s) {
    int duration = Toast.LENGTH_LONG;
    final Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, s, duration);

    toast.show();

    new CountDownTimer(5000, 1000) 
    {
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            if (toast.getView().getWindowToken() != null)
                toast.show();
            else
                cancel();
        }
        public void onFinish() {
            if (toast.getView().getWindowToken() !=null)
                toast.show();
            else
                cancel();
        }

    }.start();
}
```

If you want a longer toast, just increase the duration of the `CountDownTimer`.

Please make note of the lines

```
if (toast.getView().getWindowToken !=null)
```

If the `windowToken` of the toast is null, that is pretty much saying the Toast has already left the view, (i.e. the toast was canceled).

I found a few solutions online for increasing the duration of a toast, but I couldn't find one to preserve dismissal if the toast has been dismissed by the user.  So I pieced the above together to preserve normal Toast functionality.

Let me know what you think!

Comment: Thank you for your sharing. Can you put your hack in the answer below?

Comment: This is interesting.. cool!

Comment: A good workaround, but I believe a status bar notification would be a better suit if you intend to show something to the user that lasts longer than 3.5 seconds. But again, this is a good piece to share. Thanks.

Comment: Hey @MattK, 

Thanks for your response! 

I was thinking about a status bar notification but sadly it didn't make sense with the UI I'm working with :( lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I posted this question a little wonky, what I was really looking to do was to share this following hack with everyone on how to make a Toast duration Longer in Android:

```
public void createToast(Context context, String s) {
     int duration = Toast.LENGTH_LONG;
     final Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, s, duration);

     toast.show();

     new CountDownTimer(5000, 1000) 
     {
         public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
             if (toast.getView().getWindowToken() != null)
                 toast.show();
             else
                 cancel();
         }
         public void onFinish() {
             if (toast.getView().getWindowToken() !=null)
                 toast.show();
             else
                 cancel();
         }
     }.start();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I don't see your question. If the question is "what do you think?", I doubt about the cases where you would need a `Toast` longer than `Toast.LENGTH_LONG`. If `Toast.LENGTH_LONG` if short, probably is better to use an `AlertDialog`.

Anyway, your solution seems a little heavy... you can stack the `Toast` messages, so you could make two or more `Toast`s with the same message and instantiate one after the other. The effect of this should be what you are looking for.

Comment: Do you mean something like this:
for(int i = 0; i<9; i++){
    toast.show();
}
This would stack toasts on top of one another, but doesn't really give a longer view time of the toast than the original one toast with the duration set to Toast.LENGTH_LONG.

Comment: It works, but you need to create a new toast every iteration, not showing the same.
for(int i = 0; i<9; i++){ new toast(bla bla bla).show(); }

Comment: This is a different way of doing it; but I'm still weary about it;
I absolutely hate creating more objects than I need, it's just a developer practice that I've been trying to follow.

Thanks for sharing though!